# Why numbers converted from char to int are different than before conversion?

Tags: c#, integer, char, console-application

so, as the title says, I can't convert numbers from char to integer. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Console.Clear();
int hourBin1 = 0, hourBin2 = 0, minuteBin1 = 0, minuteBin2 = 0, secondBin1 = 0, secondBin2 = 0;
int iteration=0;
void conversion(int variable){
    int i=0;
    int[] table = new int[6];
    while(variable>0){
        table[i]=variable%2;
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} {variable} {table[i]}");
        variable/=2;
        i++;
    }
    int result = 0;
    for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--){
        result*=10;
        result+=table[j];
    }
    if(iteration==0){
        hourBin1=result;
        iteration++;
    }else if(iteration==1){
        hourBin2=result;
        iteration++;
    }else if(iteration==2){
        minuteBin1=result;
        iteration++;
    }else if(iteration==3){
        minuteBin2=result;
        iteration++;
    }else if (iteration==4){
        secondBin1=result;
        iteration++;
    }else if (iteration==5){
        secondBin2=result;
        iteration++;
    }
}
Console.Write("enter date in HH:MM:SS format to convert: ");
string numberString = Console.ReadLine()!.Trim();
char[] separation = numberString.ToCharArray();
foreach (var x in separation){
    Console.Write($"{x} ");
}
int hour1 = Convert.ToInt16(separation[0]);
int hour2 = Convert.ToInt16(separation[1]);
int minute1 = Convert.ToInt16(separation[3]);
int minute2 = Convert.ToInt16(separation[4]);
int second1 = Convert.ToInt16(separation[6]);
int second2 = Convert.ToInt16(separation[7]);
Console.WriteLine("converting to binary system");
conversion(hour1);
conversion(hour2);
conversion(minute1);
conversion(minute2);
conversion(second1);
conversion(second2);
Console.WriteLine($"\n{hour1} {hour2} {minute1} {minute2} {second1} {second2}");
Console.WriteLine($"hourBin1}\n{hourBin2}\n{minuteBin1}\n{minuteBin2}\n{secondBin1}\n{secondBin2}");
```

for example:

console outputs for "12:23:34" looks like this:

> 1 2 : 2 3 : 3 4 49 50 50 51 51 52

I want it to look like this :

> 1 2 : 2 3 : 3 4 1 2 2 3 3 4

and final output looks like this:

> 49 50 50 51 51 52 110001 110010 110010 110011 110011 110100

I want it to look like this :

> 1 2 2 3 3 4  0001 0010 0010 0011 0011 0100

PS for some reason, table cant take value smallet than 6, any ideas why?

Comment: Type right `Alt`+`4`+`9`. The Unicode character "1" sits at code point 49.

Comment: Do it like this: `int hour1 = Convert.ToInt16(separation[0].ToString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically the equivalent ASCII  values, all you can do is simply subtract 48 from each value then you will get the exact value. ASCII  value of char `1` is 49.

```
int hour1 = Convert.ToInt16(separation[0]) - 48;
```

Comment: Don't call that ASCII please, even though it's backwards compatible, Unicode has been around for three decades already.

Comment: @CodeCaster precisely yes, you are right :)

Comment: ooooh, okay, it worked, but is there a way to assign value right away without subtraction?

Comment: you can try `var number = Convert.ToInt16(ch.ToString());` . please accept the answer if it has answered your questoin